# Emojis on flutter web are not displayed

Tags: flutter, emoji, flutter-web

I try to use emojis on flutter web, for example , on a `Text()` widget, but the emoji does not appear and I get a cross instead.

**Screenshot**:
[image]

**Code:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(body: Text('This is an emoji ')),
    );
  }
}
```

Do you know how to solve it on flutter web ?

Comment: Flutter web is not ready yet, it is better not to use it for production

Answer (score 0):

`can try flutter_emoji package` : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_emoji

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is already solved on Flutter 2.8

I just copy pasted the emoji on the Text string as follows.

```dart
   Center(
     child: AppCard(
       child: Text(
         'Hi there ',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

[image: Flutter web screenshot]